# how to show multiple graphs at once? (class)

Tags: python, class, matplotlib

Hi everyone:) I would like to ask for some help to make a class that I can use to plot graphs. i have an excel sheet with different countries and their corresponding air pollution levels. i need to plot graphs for each country. this is the code used to plot my graphs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = df_full_filtered.loc[(df_full_filtered['AirPollutant'] == 'PM10') & (df_full_filtered['Country'] 
 == 'Italy')]['AirPollutionLevel']

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.hist(x, bins=80)
plt.show()

y = df_full_filtered.loc[(df_full_filtered['AirPollutant'] == 'PM10') & (df_full_filtered['Country'] 
== 'Germany')]['AirPollutionLevel']

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.hist(y, bins=80)
plt.show()
```

everytime i run my code, it stops running everytime it reaches the plt.show code and wont continue running till you manually close the popup window with the first graph. is there any way i can surpass this?

edit: i tried putting both codes for x and y under each other and inserting plt.plot(x,y) but they have different shapes (rows/columns in the excel file)

thanks

Comment: Do you want to plot each country in a separate figure or do want to plot them side-by-side in a [grid of subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)? The latter option lets you share the y-axis and makes it easier to compare the countries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two figures.

*Method 1*

```
data = [i**2 for i in range(100)]

plt.figure(1)
plt.hist(data, bins = 5)

plt.figure(2)
plt.hist(data, bins = 10)

plt.show()
```

*Method 2*

```
data = [i**2 for i in range(100)]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.hist(data, bins = 5)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.hist(data, bins = 10)

plt.show()
```

(If you need, you can call them the same name, i.e. the second figure and axes could be named fig1 and ax1, as well.)

Method 1 is the direct answer to your code. Method 2 is another way of using Matplotlib. (see https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/)